# Django-Pjax not working in Django 1.5

Tags: python, ajax, django, single-page-application, pjax

I am trying to figure out how to use pjax in django.  I am using django-pjax here: https://github.com/jacobian/django-pjax.  I know for sure that my pjax is working because I have it alerting me when I click a pjax link, but it is still not rendering the content in the same html page.  I think the problem has to do with django-pjax.  I am using django 1.5.  Here is my code:

The view for the page that has the link I am clicking and where I want to change content:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from djpjax import pjax, pjaxtend

@pjax()
def index(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'shuttleservice/index.html', {})
```

The view for the page I want to show up when I click the link:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from djpjax import pjax, pjaxtend

@pjax()
def from_ap_form(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'orders/from_ap_form.html', {})
```

The html for the div I want to replace:

```
{% extends 'shuttleservice/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block pagetitle %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block primary %}
<div id="booking-form-home"> <!-- div I want to replace -->
    <p>Are you looking to book a private airport shuttle?  <a href='#'>Click here</a>. </p>
    <h2> Book Airport Shuttle </h2>

    <ul class="booking-nav-bar">
        <li class="booking-nav-button">
            <a class="booking-nav-text" href='orders/from_ap_form'>From Airport</a> <!-- link I am pressing to use pjax -->
        </li>

        <li class="booking-nav-button">
            <a class="booking-nav-text" href='#'>To Airport</a>
        </li>

        <li class="booking-nav-button">
            <a class="booking-nav-text" href='#'>From/To Airport</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- more content -->
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).pjax('a', '#booking-form-home');

    $(document).on('pjax:click', function() { alert('hello');});
});
```

The alert works correctly so pjax is firing.  Does anyone know any reason why pjax would not work in this case?  Django-pjax is supposed to be so easy to implement but I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours now.  Also, I do realize I am selecting all links with pjax, but I am just doing that until I can get pjax working.  Thank you!

Comment: Can someone confirm whether I did the django-pjax part right?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately right now Django-PJAX requires Django 1.3.

Latest commit was authored on Mar 14, 2012...

Answer (score 0):

As phedoreanu said, Django-PJAX requires Django 1.3

However, There is [django-easy-pjax](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-easy-pjax/) which works with Django 1.5+ and was last updated last month